# When installing an SSL certificate the control panel css breaks

Tags: control-panel, css, ssl

I've installed an SSL certificate on a domain and that has the lovely green padlock. However when I log into the control panel, all of the CSS is broken.
Any ideas on what I should be doing?
CHeers

Comment: Can you upload Backend panel console log errors?

Comment: Hi Mufi. I have to admit being a bit of a noob so where would I find that?

Comment: Right click on anywhere in the browser. Click on inspect element. You will see option named console. See if there is any errors there

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the protocol from the Default base URL in system settings > URL and Path Settings, so you have:

//yourdomain.com/

instead of

http://yourdomain.com/

Answer (score 1):

check your theme folder url. most likely that is set to http

Comment: Hi Jelle. I've set the themes folder to to https and still the css isn't playing :-(

Comment: Try clearing the cache and check that all your url are https in the Setting -> Path and Url

Comment: also check your config file to see if that is not overruling stuff

Comment: I try and set the theme folder url to https and it just refuses to change- just bounces back to http. wtf?

Comment: @Inigo I get the same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: Check wether your htaccess isn't messing things up
next check your admin.php file for any mentions of http://
Also check the path settings in the cp. What version of EE are you on?